# Generate diff report of pair of files

Tags: shell, command

I have thousands of flat files in two directories `dir1` and `dir2`. Now, I want to generate diff report of the pair of same file names in two other different directories `success` (if diff is exactly same) and `failure` (if diff is not same).

For example:
if `dir1` has files: `file1, file2`
and if `dir2` has files: `file2, file3`

Then I'd take the diff of `dir1/file2` and `dir2/file2` only. `file1` and `file3` will be ignored as they don't have their respective pairs.

How can I do it using shell script? Is it possible using system commands?

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying what kind of reports you want to see in your "success"
and "failure" directories, so not including that in the solution. Also, using
"cmp" instead of "diff" as you don't exactly specify that you need the "diff"
output and what kind of.

```
for p1 in dir1/*; do
    f=`basename "$p1"`
    p2="dir2/$f"
    if [ -e "$p2" ]; then
        if cmp --quiet "$p1" "$p2"; then
            echo "$f: success"
        else
            echo "$f: failure"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Substitute "echo's" with your report generation. Replace "cmp" with "diff" and
appropriate options, if necessary.

Comment: I'd throw in a `[ -f "$p1" ]` and also exchange the `-e` with an `-f`, just in case.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, but this would reduce the clarity and would be not far from adding "-r" and other checks, which would obscure the meaning further, in the end solving a far more complicated problem than presented in the question. This could also hide a potential problem.

Comment: How would this hide a potential problem? If there are subfolders in the directories, it will break like this. Proper checking could *warn* of a potential problem, instead of trying to compare apples and bananas. We don't know exactly how the OPs folder structure looks like, and the OP should at least know about potential problems.

Comment: Adrian, I assume you wanted to ignore non-files. Now according to the question, the directories contain files. The question doesn't specify if there could be directories or not. Now, let's assume that there *are* directories. My version will report errors for them, but your will not. In case directories are there on purpose, errors will still not lose data. However, if they're there not on purpose, but as a result of an error generating the input, then my version will highlight this. Your version will hide data loss on input generation. And we can't say that the OP knows about problems.

Comment: I did not specify how to use the safety checks, so assuming that my version (which doesn't even exist) would hide errors is a little far-fetched. You know, you can do `[ ! -f "${file}" ] && echo "skipping non-file "${file}" && continue` after all. Also, I fail to see how it would end with data loss since the OP specifically requested to ignore files which don't have a matching brother and I would not exactly call "skipping directories" "data loss".

Comment: Mind that I'm not trying to summon an argument and I +1'd your answer anyway, I was just noting a detail ;-)

Comment: Adrian, yes, you can do a message on skipping non-files, however, once again, the question didn't ask to solve that problem and "cmp" would produce a clear error about that anyway, so there is little sense in adding that check besides ignoring that. Regarding data loss, consider whatever process that produced these two directories that our solutions will process. There could have been an error which resulted in creating a directory instead of one or several files in some cases. Ignoring directories in this case would hide that fact, resulting in data loss going unnoticed.

Comment: And your version does exist, since we're discussing it, albeit not posted anywhere and not completely clear to me.